# Google play store licence limitations

Tags: google-play-services, apk, google-apps-marketplace, google-developers-console

I designed an app and want to sell it on Google Play but have some doubts about it and I hope you can help me:

1) Is it possible to limit the quantity of downloads of my app from Google play (i.e: 2.000 downloads)?

2) Is it possible to make a configuration on Google play Developers Console, to offer an annual renewable licence for the customers who buy my app? If so, can you please tell me how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Is it possible to limit the quantity of downloads of my app from Google play (i.e: 2.000 downloads)?**

I don't think this is possible, checked with the Play Developer Console and there's no setting there about it. Checked with the Play Developer API and it doesn't list on any calls there any "total number of downloads".

**2) Is it possible to make a configuration on Google play Developers Console, to offer an annual renewable licence for the customers who buy my app? If so, can you please tell me how to do it?**

[In-App Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) looks like what you're looking for, a yearly subscription (or how frequent you want it) set for the application usage would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

as for questions 1, im pretty sure this isnt a current feature. as for question 2, you could create a script in the apk that disables everything in the app when a certain in-app purchase runs out until its renewed.